# How to compute the exponential of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, exponential-function, linear-transformations

I am trying to prove all the results regarding linear algebra in my ODE class. I have already convinced myself that if I have a matrix $T$ which has an eigenvalue $\lambda = a + ib$ and an associated eigenvector $v = u + iw$ I can always "almost diagonalize" $T$ using $T = PDP^{-1}$ where $P = [u | v]$ is the real canonical base and $D = \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}$

When it comes to linear systems of ODE's, using matrix exponentials, I just don't get why $e^{Dt} = e^{at}\begin{pmatrix} \cos bt & \sin bt\\ -\sin bt & \cos at\end{pmatrix}$

As far as I know, you can transform $D$ in sines and cosines forms factoring out  $\rho = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and getting:

$D = \rho \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta\\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}$, where $\tan \theta = \frac{b}{a}$.

I can't see the connexion between these two forms and how one would get rid $\theta$ for example, when calculating the exponential via the infinite series form. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $D=aI+bJ$, $I=$identity matrix, and $J=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$. 
\begin{align*}
\exp tD & =\exp\left(taI\right)\exp\left(tbJ\right)\\
 & =\begin{bmatrix}e^{ta} & 0\\
0 & e^{ta}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos bt & \sin bt\\
-\sin bt & \cos bt
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & =e^{ta}\begin{bmatrix}\cos bt & \sin bt\\
-\sin bt & \cos bt
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Was just writing this, with this exact notation... +1.

Comment: You may want to add why you can split the exponential into a product. The answer is of course that I and J commute (because I commutes with everything).

Comment: Agreed. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, please correct me if I'm wrong: one can only write $exp(A+B) = exp(A)exp(B)$ if and only if $AB=BA$. Right? Thanks a lot for the support.